# NASM not reading ctrl-d character

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am writing a simple NASM assembler program. I have about 95% of it figured out. However, I am running into one problem I cannot seem to figure out. Hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> is supposed to display a goodbye message and then terminate the program. Here's a skeleton of what I have

```
Section .bss
    Buff resb2
    BuffLen equ $-Buff

loop:
    ; some code
    mov ecx, Buff
    move edx, BuffLen
    ; some code
    cmp ecx, 0x04
    je Exit
    jne loop
```

According to the ASCII chart, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> is 0x04. I must be missing something simple. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: 1) Does your program work correctly for other codes, especially printable ones?  2) Depending on what sort of terminal you are using to interact with your program, it is possible that CTRL-D is getting trapped or translated there.

Comment: Besides what Chris mentions, you're comparing `ecx`, the address of `Buff`, with `0x04`. Highly unlikely! Try `cmp byte [ecx], 0x04`.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, was writing another assignment. I tried with ctrl_j (0x0A) and got it to work just fine. This leads me to believe something is up with ctrl+d. Frank, I implemented your suggestion as well.

Comment: To check if Chris Stratton is right you may try a C program and check if Ctrl+D is read by the C program.

Comment: In a C program on Unix/Linux, a ctrl-D will come through as an EOF on the standard input. So the operating system is interpreting it and not just passing through a `0x04`.

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> you type doesn't become part of the input. Rather, it's a signal to your terminal to send an EOF condition on the standard input file stream. Your program should respond to the standard input being in an EOF state. (For example, on Posix, a `read(2)` system call would return zero.)

Comment: `ctrl-d` only sends EOF if you type it on an empty line.  If you type some text before `ctrl-d`, it just "sends" that text (i.e. makes `read` return) without making it return EOF.  Try it out with `cat`.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: in POSIX a `ctrl-d` always makes a `read` system call return if it was blocked waiting for input from a cooked TTY.  The return value is the length of the line-editing input; `read() == 0` means EOF so `ctrl-d` on an empty line should be interpreted that way, but isn't really a special case for the cooked input processing in the kernel.  There isn't a special EOF signal other than read() return values; if a program makes another `read()` system call after one returns zero, you could type more stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing "cmp ecx, 0x04" you can try out "cmp eax, 0". Because after hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the return value of the read system call in Linux will be 0 bytes and this "0" will be saved in the eax-Register.

PS: I am not 100% sure on how it works, because i have a problem with that at the moment, too. But this way I can quit my programm most of the time at least.